# Typescript: Avoid comparison by reference

Tags: javascript, web, reference, comparison, typescript

I need to store a list of points and check if a new point is already included in that list

```
class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var points : Point[] = [];
    points.push(new Point(1,1));
    var point = new Point(1,1);
    alert(points.indexOf(point)); // -1 
}
```

Obviously typescript uses comparison by reference but in this case that doesn't make sense. In Java or C# I would overload the `equals` method, in typescript that doesn't seem to be possible.

I considered to loop through the array with `foreach` and check each entry for equality, but that seems rather complicated and would bloat the code.

Is there something like `equals` in typescript ? How can I implement my own comparisons ?

Comment: Typescript is a metalanguage, not a language. You should ask "Is there something like equals in javascript", not typescript.

Comment: Where / how are you doing the comparison in your script?

Comment: @danludwig, typescript has generics. they could have implemented custom container classes that check for something like equals. an interface icomparable and a generic class arraylist<T where T implements icomparable> would do the job.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think dart provides something like `hashcode` and you can override it. http://pchalin.blogspot.com/2014/04/defining-equality-and-hashcode-for-dart.html

Comment: Might be a worthy alternative to Typescript?

Comment: Also, frameworks like Vue provide an option to set "key" to identify objects so it's handy. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html `v-bind:key`

Comment: In WPF there's `SelectedValuePath` perhaps? To avoid overriding `Equals`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap the collection in a `PointList` that only allows `Point` objects to be added via an `add` method, which checks to ensure no duplicates are added.

This has the benefit of encapsulating the "No duplicates" rule in a single place, rather than hoping that all calling code will check before adding a duplicate, which would duplicate the rule in many places.

```
class Point {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {
    }
}

class PointList {
    private points: Point[] = [];

    get length() {
        return this.points.length;
    }

    add(point: Point) {
        if (this.exists(point)) {
            // throw 'Duplicate point';
            return false;
        }

        this.points.push(point);
        return true;
    }

    exists(point: Point) {
        return this.findIndex(point) > -1;
    }

    findIndex(point: Point) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            var existingPoint = this.points[i];
            if (existingPoint.x === point.x && existingPoint.y === point.y) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}

var pointList = new PointList();

var pointA = new Point(1, 1);
var pointB = new Point(1, 1);
var pointC = new Point(1, 2);

pointList.add(pointA);
alert(pointList.length); // 1

pointList.add(pointB);
alert(pointList.length); // 1

pointList.add(pointC);
alert(pointList.length); // 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, although I would rather call this class **`PointSet`** instead of `PointList` as the functionality is exactly that of a set. But then, you'd have to change `length()` to `size()` and `exists()` to `has()` to better match the methods available for a Typescript set.

Answer (score 5):

Typescript doesn't add any functionality to JavaScript. It's just "typed" and some syntax improvements.

So, there's not a way to override `equals` in an equivalent way to what you might have done in C#.

However, you would have ended up likely using a `Hash` or a strongly-typed `Dictionary` in C# to do an efficient lookup (in addition to the array potentially), rather than using an "index of" function.

For that, I'd just suggest you use an associative array structure to store the `Point`s.

You'd do something like:

```
class Point {
    constructor(public x:Number = 0, 
        public y:Number = 0 ) {     
    }   
    public toIndexString(p:Point):String {
        return Point.pointToIndexString(p.x, p.y);  
    }       
    static pointToIndexString(x:Number, y:Number):String {
        return x.toString() + "@" + y.toString();   
    }       
}

var points:any = {};
var p: Point = new Point(5, 5);
points[p.toIndexString()] = p;
```

If a `Point` doesn't exist, checking the `points` associative array will returned `undefined`.

A function wrapping the array would be simple:

```
function findPoint(x:Number, y:Number):Point {
    return points[Point.pointToIndexString(x, y)];
}
```

Looping through all points would be easy to:

```
// define the callback (similar in concept to defining delegate in C#)
interface PointCallback {
    (p:Point):void;
}

function allPoints(callback:PointCallback):void {
    for(var k in points) {
        callback(points[k]);
    }
}

allPoints((p) => {
   // do something with a Point...
});
```

Comment: great, thanks for the answer. i ended up implementing a custom list type like the one in steve fentons answer. but this looks nice, too

Comment: If you're doing much searching, his solution is currently O(n). Not ideal from a perf perspective. An associative array would be super fast.

Comment: how can an associative array be faster than O(n) ? It has to check all keys, too. Instead of comparing strings he's comparing points. Correct me if i'm wrong, but i don't see the difference.

Comment: An associative array uses a hash, which often is O(1).

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is try out [linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/). With that, you can do something like this:

```
var foundPoint = Enumerable.From(points)
    .SingleOrDefault(function(p) {
        return p.x == targetX && p.y == targety;
    });
```

... you could then just implement this function on your object

```
class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    static equals(points: Point[], candidate: Point): boolean {
        var foundPoint = Enumerable.From(points)
            .SingleOrDefault((p: Point): boolean => {
                return p.x == candidate.x && p.y == candidate.y;
             });
        return foundPoint != null;
    }
}
```

... and use it like this

```
var points = createPointsArray();
var point = getSomePoint();
// is point already in array?
var isPointInPoints = Point.equals(points, point)
```

Comment: @lhk If you do go this route, DefinitelyTyped has the Typescript d.ts for linq.js: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/linq

Comment: nice, ill definitely read up on linqjs. for now i used a custom list like the one in steve fentons answer

Answer (score 2):

### Solution using a `Set`

I thought that a Set would be a perfect fit for this kind of problem since:

> A value in the Set may only occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection.  — [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

However, you can still add `[0, 1, 2, 3]` multiples times to a Set (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/9655481)) since Sets use the [`SameValueZero(x, y)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevaluezero) comparison algorithm to compare values (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36589013/9655481)). That's why you have to implement your own version of a Set.

#### Custom Set implemenation

I ported [Johnny Bueti's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782664/johnny-bueti) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66597517/9655481) to Sets. I don't overwrite any prototype as that is considered [bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes) and can have unwanted side-effects.

Inside `util.ts`:

```js
export interface Equatable {
    /**
    * Returns `true` if the two objects are equal, `false` otherwise.
    */
    equals(object: any): boolean
}

export class SetCustomEquals<T extends Equatable> extends Set<T>{

    add(value: T) {
        if (!this.has(value)) {
            super.add(value);
        }
        return this;
    }

    has(otherValue: T): boolean {
        for (const value of this.values()) {
            if (otherValue.equals(value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```js
import { Equatable, SetCustomEquals } from "./util";

class MyClass implements Equatable {

    equals(other: MyClass): boolean {
        ... (your custom code)
    }

}

const mySet= new SetCustomEquals<MyClass>();
const myObject = new MyClass();
mySet.add(myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement my own comparison method. In this instance I'm extending the `Array.prototype` - which I would not suggest unless you know exactly what you're doing - but you can very well create your own class that inherits from `Array` and implements a `.contains()` method like the one defined below.

```
interface Equatable {
  /**
  * Returns `true` if the two objects are equal, `false` otherwise.
  */
  equals(object: any): boolean
}

class Point implements Equatable {
  public equals(toPoint: Point): boolean {
    return this.x === toPoint.x && this.y === toPoint.y;
  }
}

// Augment the global scope
declare global {
  interface Array<T extends Equatable> {
    /**
    * Returns `true` if an object is found, `false` otherwise. This method uses the `.equals()` method to compare `Equatable` objects for equality.
    */
    contains(object: T): boolean
  }
}

// Extend the Array.prototype.
Array.prototype.contains = function(object: Equatable) {
  return this.findIndex(element => {
    return element.equals(object);
  }) !== -1;
}
```

The `Equatable` interface allows you to extend this behaviour to any other object:

```js
class User implements Equatable {
  public equals(toUser: User): boolean {
    return this.uuid === toUser.uuid;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 interesting answer. But I'm thinking: wouldn't be better to use generics? I would expect something like: `class User implements Equatable<User>` to be sure that equals gets called with a User object. What do you think?

Comment: That could definitely work, yes! I do remember having a very odd and specific issue with making `Equatable` generic, but not quite which was it.