# Why does two equal Objects shows 'not equal" in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I Upload array from json file.
every 1.5 second I check if there are any changes in file (at the moment I test on one file without any changes), but when I check if

```
    if ( this.itemsParentArray[i] !== this.itemInArray[i] )
```

it always shows that it's not equal, and console.log (""not equal")

Did I missed something in code??Here it is:

```
export class HomeComponent {
itemsParentArray = [];
itemInArray = [];
myRes: Content;
showAssigned:boolean = false;

constructor(private structureRequest: StructureRequestService) {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.timerGetStructure();
    }, 1500);
}
//  using with setInterval to get new data and sets into content Array with this.updateItems(result) if it's new

timerGetStructure() {
    this.structureRequest.sendRequest().subscribe((result) => this.updateItems(result));
}
updateItems(result) {
    this.myRes =  result;
    this.itemInArray = this.myRes.content;
    for ( let i = 0; i < this.itemInArray.length; i++) {
                if ( this.itemsParentArray[i] !== this.itemInArray[i] ) {
                   // this.itemsParentArray[i] = this.itemInArray[i];
                   console.log("not equal");
                }
            }
}

//
ngOnInit() {
    //makes http request and puts result into parentArray after 3 sec.
    this.structureRequest.sendRequest().subscribe((result) => this.viewNodes(result));
}
//view items
viewNodes(result) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.myRes =  result;
        this.itemsParentArray = this.myRes.content;
        this.showAssigned = true;
    }, 3000);
}
}
```

As you see it loads data from the same file (I do not change file data!!!):

```
this.itemsParentArray = this.myRes.content;
```

and (each 1.5 sec):

```
this.itemInArray = this.myRes.content;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`==` and especially `===` don't check if the object contains the same properties with the same values. It just checks if it is the same object reference.

```
{} == {}
```

or

```
{} === {}
```

also result in `false`.

See also [Typescript: Avoid comparison by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406384/typescript-avoid-comparison-by-reference) and [How do I initialize a typescript object with a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object)

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3wPrlTDkznQEhy0K799n?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this helper function in TypeScript:

```
export class Helper {
    private _recursiveProperties: string[] = ['RecursiveProperty', ...];

    public equals(obj1: any, obj2: any): boolean {
        if (typeof obj1 !== typeof obj2) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((obj1 === undefined && obj2 !== undefined) ||
            (obj2 === undefined && obj1 !== undefined) ||
            (obj1 === null && obj2 !== null) ||
            (obj2 === null && obj1 !== null)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (typeof obj1 === 'object') {
            if (Array.isArray(obj1)) {
                if (!Array.isArray(obj2) || obj1.length !== obj2.length) {
                    return false;
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
                    if (!this.equals(obj1[i], obj2[i])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (let prop in obj1) {
                    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        if (!obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        //Endless loop fix for recursive properties
                        if (this._recursiveProperties.indexOf(prop) >= 0) {
                            if (obj1[prop] !== obj2[prop]) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else if (!this.equals(obj1[prop], obj2[prop])) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (let prop in obj2) {
                    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return obj1 === obj2;
    }
}
```

Where `_recursiveProperties` contains the names of the (if any) properties that cause an infinite loop. E.g. I had an object (obj1) with a property which contained a reference to another object (obj2) which in turn contained a reference to obj1.

If anyone has a better solution, please make a comment.

Usage would then be:

```
let helper = new Helper();
if (helper.equals(this.itemsParentArray[i], this.itemInArray[i]))
```

Comment: A solution to the recursive properties problem would be to keep a list of visited properties and only recurse when visiting novel properties.

Answer (score 2):

For me comparing two objects in Angular 2/4 I tried below code. which totally worked.

***JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);***